# i have just started to learn android studio, , i was learning to change appicon and this error pops up and now even hello world wont run

Tags: flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\collc\StudioProjects\untitled111\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.untitled111:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

Comment: i don't know how but it's working now.thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your emulator and make sure your android studio is up to date.

Comment: i reinstalled android studio